# HTML - Button mutiplies and disappears

Tags: php, html, css

Hello Stack Overflowers,

Hopefully someone can solve this riddle.
I wrote this HTML code for a donate button. And it works perfectly well.
Now, when I place it within a widget in WordPress, it shows multiple
buttons. When I click on it, it goes to the link, but the button disappears.
does anyone know what the exact problem is?
Thank you

```
<div onclick="location.href='https://aol.com/';" class="result15823794" 
style="background-image:     

url(&quot;https://s25.postimg.org/4cld27ruz/button_RAY.png&quot;);width: 
180px; height: 45px;" 
    " onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage 
='url(https://s25.postimg.org/s4uodqtvv/button_RAYbrdr.png)'
        " onmouseout="this.style.backgroundImage =     
        'url(https://s25.postimg.org/4cld27ruz/button_RAY.png)'" 
onclick="location.href='https://aol.com/';">
        <div style="background-image:     
url(https://s25.postimg.org/6sn6g29xn/button_RA.gif)
        width: 180px; height: 45px;">
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: all i can say... this code is a big mess

Comment: There is an extra quote here: `height: 45px;"  ["] onmouseover` but I'm not sure if that's what's causing your issue... why not use an `a` tag with an `href` instead of a `div`?

Comment: There is a lot of extras like: `&quot;`, single quote in the wrong places and a rogue semi colon with `location.href`. Fix those and then maybe someone can look at it again.

Comment: Thanks Syfer , Jesse Kernaghan. Let me try what you both have suggested. and we'll see what it does. I appreciate you both.

Comment: Try to correct the other errors as well, such as the missing semicolon after the last url. And do yourself a favour and remove all returns from the attribute values.

Comment: @Syfer Semicolons after JavaScript statements are perfectly valid. Also, it's a good idea to put urls in the `url(..)` property in quotes, although I must admit that `&quot;` is not the one I would have chosen.

Comment: @lister I completely missed the location.href, my bad, but yeah the `&quot;` seems to be a result of copy pasting into an editor which shouldn't be too hard to fix. Also the single quotes.